# Centering a javascript graphics window

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and I need to figure out how to make a javascript applet that is centered in my webpage.  Can anyone link me to a resource that will show me how to do this?

Comment: ...you mean a Java applet ?  Java has applets, not javascript

Comment: You're right applet was the wrong word.  I made a javascript script that displays a graphics window using O3D and I want to center this window.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="width:320px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  <!-- applet goes here -->
</div>
```

This assumes the applet is 320px wide.